# Importação de xml NFE em grande quantidade C# e Sql Server

Tags: .net, winforms, xml, sql-server

Bom dia!
Tenho uma aplicação com as seguintes características:

1. Windows Forms,
2. C#
3. Visual Studio Community 2019
4. Sql Server Express
5. Windows 10 Pro

**Sobre:**
Criei a aplicação com objetivo de importar para o Sql Server notas fiscais eletrônicas por meio dos xml's, a importação é massiva, na ordem de centenas de milhares de arquivos xml, gerando milhões de registros. Como referência, a ideia é importar 3 milhões de arquivos xml em menos de 8 horas.

**Problema**
O início da importação tem uma velocidade muito boa e conforme avança, após algum tempo, normalmente 20% da importação o desempenho sofre abruptas quedas na importação e assim vai de forma exponencial até praticamente parar de importar os arquivos.

**O que já foi feito**
A ideia é ler o diretório onde estão os arquivos dentro de um laço de repetição, obtendo desta forma um arquivo por vez, deserializando baseado no xsd da fazenda. Este processo aparentemente está rápido e não me parece ser a raiz do problema, inicialmente eu utilizei o Entity Framework Core com repository pattern para os inserts, a cada arquivo importado eu instanciava as classes que representam minhas tabelas no sql server passando os valores deserializados via contrutor, código abaixo é um exemplo:

```
var nFe_obsCont = new NFe_obsCont(nfeId, obsCont.xTexto, obsCont.xCampo);
                        new EmpresaRepository<NFe_obsCont>().Adicionar(nFe_obsCont);
```

Isso foi feito com todas as outras classes, lembrando que em um único arquivo de nfe, podem existir até 990 produtos, o ForEach de leitura de um arquivo possui outros 2 laços dentro, um para produtos e outro para impostos, digo isso pois é o tipo de coisa que afeta o desempenho, pelo motivo de ter inúmeras validações, caso campos não tenham valores.

Alerto que esse modelo descrito acima foi abandonado, pois utilizando o EF Core o desempenho com grande quantidade foi muito ruim, apesar do EF Core ter melhorado e muito, em comparação a versão anterior.

**O que eu fiz para melhorar**
Para melhorar o desempenho eu refatorei a importação e passei a utilizar SqlBulkCopy, então neste momento eu passei a carregar minhas classes (Tabelas Sql Server) em um DataTable e a cada 10 mil registros e chamo meu método, que despeja os dados no sql server, seguindo o código abaixo:

```
public class SqlServerBulkCopy
{
    public event LinhasAfetadasEventHandler LinhasAfetadasEvent;
    private string tableName;
    public void BulkData(DataTable dt)
    {
        if (dt.Rows.Count <= 0)
            return;

        tableName = string.Empty;
        tableName = dt.TableName;

        using (var bulkCopy = new SqlBulkCopy(_minhaStringConexao))
        {
            bulkCopy.DestinationTableName = $"dbo.{dt.TableName}";
            bulkCopy.ColumnMappings.Clear();

            foreach (DataColumn column in dt.Columns)
                bulkCopy.ColumnMappings.Add(column.ColumnName, column.ColumnName);
                    
            try
            {
                bulkCopy.NotifyAfter = dt.Rows.Count;
                bulkCopy.SqlRowsCopied += OnSqlRowsCopied;
                bulkCopy.BatchSize = 5000;
                bulkCopy.BulkCopyTimeout = 60;
                bulkCopy.WriteToServer(dt);
                bulkCopy.Close();
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(ex.ToString());
            }
        }
    }

    private void OnSqlRowsCopied(object sender, SqlRowsCopiedEventArgs e)
    {
        LinhasAfetadasEvent?.Invoke(sender, e, tableName);
    }
}
```

Aparentemente eu havia tido sucesso e ao fazer uma importação relativamente grande, a importação se comportou bem e manteve uma regularidade ao longo das importações dos arquivos, porém ao tentar importar  pouco mais de 2 milhões arquivos, ele importou 10% em quase 11 horas, ou seja, voltei a estaca zero, o comportamento permanece o mesmo, em grande quantidade, chega um ponto onde parece ir exponencialmente perdendo a capacidade de importação, apesar de em todo meu código revisar se eu estava liberando alguns recursos e assim me certificar, percebo que a questão não é na aplicação e sim no banco, ressalto que as tabelas não possuem relacionamentos entre si, prevendo isso eu criei índice clusterizado e como tipo inteiro, pois no passado minha pk era tipo Guid, o que foi muito ruim para esse modelo, já que mesmo sendo clusterizado o sql server precisa reorganizar ao fazer os inserts.

**O que estou fazendo**

Até o momento estou testando incluir o DataTable inteiro ao final da leitura, ainda estou testando isso, mas me preocupa isso, pois eu não saberei sempre o tamanho das inclusões e isso pode ter um impacto ruim se a base for gigante. Após muita busca, encontrei gente que grava arquivos txt e depois importa via bulkCopy, mas ainda não tentei esta abordagem e sinceramente para mim não faria o menor sentido.

Bom se alguém tiver alguma dica sobre a importação de milhões de registros e puder compartilhar!

Obrigado